# Specialized Allez Sprint Fork

Tags: fork, headset

I have a 2019 Specialized Allez Sprint Frame. I need a replacement fork, but specialized does not stock them. Are there any aftermarket forks that will fit this frame? If so, do they require a new headset?

Here is a photo of the OEM fork illustrating the integrated race and gap below the race, which I believe will make it challenging to find an aftermarket fork that will fit.

[image: specialized allez sprint fork]

Comment: What happened to such a new bike that the fork needs replacing already ?  Was it crash damage ?

Answer (score 2):

Aftermarket forks are available for pretty much any bike frame.

To fit the frame there are three things to consider, length, steerer diameter and taper, and brake mounting.

The length is usually measured 'axle to crown', which means the center of the axle to where the fork meets the frame head tube.

The steerer diameter and taper (larger size bottom bearing) have to match the headset bearings in the frame. I believe the [2019 Allez Sprint](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/shop/Bikes/Road-Bikes/Performance-Road-Bikes/Allez/c/allez) has a 1-1/8" to 1-1/2" taper steerer.

Obviously you need either a rim or disc brake fork.

Comment: All good points, unfortunately, the Allez Sprint has a gap below the standard bottom headset bearing, it is about 10mm. If you look at the Allez fork, it has a tall section, then the integrated crown race. I think this will cause an issue with aftermarket forks and not sure how to solve.

Comment: @BMW have you contacted Specialized directly?

Comment: Yes they will send a replacement, just wondering if any aftermarket solutions exist. Added a photo so you can see what I'm referring to.